# Counting lines ignored by grep

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

Let me try to explain this as clearly as I can...

I have a script that at some point does this:

```
grep -vf ignore.txt input.txt
```

This ignore.txt has a bunch of lines with things I want my grep to ignore, hence the -v (meaning I don't want to see them in the output of grep).

Now, what I want to do is I want to be able to know how many lines of input.txt have been ignored by each line of ignore.txt.

For example, if ignore.txt had these lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I would like to know how many lines of input.txt were ignored by ignoring line1, how many by ignoring line2, and so on.

Any ideas on how can I do this?

I hope that made sense... Thanks!

Comment: Is it important to use grep? Or would you consider a solution that uses `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: sed or awk would work too. This is all part of a perl script, so that would work too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the number of lines matched by the pattern from a line from ignore.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sum of the ignored lines plus the shown lines may NOT add up to the total number of lines...  "line1 and line2 are here" will be counted twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

local @ARGV = 'ignore.txt';
chomp(my @pats = <>);

foreach my $pat (@pats) {
    print "$pat: ", qx/grep -c $pat input.txt/;
}
```

Comment: You're calling the external `grep` utility repeatedly (potentially _many_ times) in a loop which will not only spawn the utility many times, but it will read the whole input file _each_ time! Perl can do the job without all that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-count-total-number-of-occurrences)

```
grep -o pattern file | wc -l
```

counts the total number of a given pattern in the file. A solution, given this and the information, that you already use a script, is to use several grep instances to filter and count the patterns, which you want to ignore.

However, I'd try to build a more comfortable solution involving a scripting language like e.g. python.

Comment: That was my first instinct too, but that doesn't solve his problem, since he's not asking for the total, but the number per line in the pattern file.

Comment: @flesk well, correct me, if I'm wrong, but if he uses multiple instances of grep - read: one instance for each pattern - he gets the number of ignored lines per pattern, doesn't he? This will be the case at least in the described problem - given, that each pattern is a wohle line to ignore (s. ignore.txt example given above).

Comment: He's only using one instance of grep. The `-f` switch makes grep read patterns from a file, which are then matched against `input.txt`. When you pipe that to `wc -l` you will only get the total.

Comment: Better use `grep -c` instead of `grep ... | wc -l`.

Comment: `grep -o -f ignore.txt input.txt | sort | uniq -c` would work, but this gives matches per pattern not non-matches.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# seq 1 15 | sed '/^1/!d' | sed -n '$='
7
```

Explanation:

Delete all lines except those that match. Pipe these matching (ignored) lines to another `sed` command. Delete all these lines but show the line number only of the last line. So in this example 1 thru 15, lines 1,10 thru 15 are ignored - a total of 7 lines.

EDIT:

Sorry misread the question (still a little confused!):

```
 sed 's,.*,sed "/&/!d;s/.*/matched &/" input.txt| uniq -c,' ignore.txt | sh
```

This shows the number of `matches` for each pattern in the the `ignore.txt`

```
 sed 's,.*,sed "/&/d;s/.*/non-matched &/" input.txt | uniq -c,' ignore.txt | sh
```

This shows the number of `non-matches` for each pattern in the the `ignore.txt`

If using `GNU sed`, these should work too:

```
sed 's,.*,sed "/&/!d;s/.*/matched &/" input.txt | uniq -c,;e' ignore.txt
```

or

```
sed 's,.*,sed "/&/d;s/.*/non-matched &/" input.txt | uniq -c,;e' ignore.txt
```

N.B. Your success with patterns may vary i.e. check for meta characters beforehand.

On reflection I thought this can be improved to:

```
sed 's,.*,/&/i\\matched &,;$a\\d' ignore.txt | sed -f - input.txt | sort -k2n | uniq -c
```

or

```
sed 's,.*,/&/!i\\non-matched &,;$a\\d' ignore.txt | sed -f - input.txt | sort -k2n | uniq -c
```

But NO, on large files this is actually slower.

Answer (score 0):

This script will count the matched lines by hash lookup and save the lines to be printed in `@result`, where you may process them as you will. To emulate grep, just print them.

I made the script so it can print out an example. To use with the files, uncomment the code in the script, and comment the ones marked `# example line`.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;  # example line

# Example data. 
my @ignore = ('line1' .. 'line9'); # example line
my @input  = ('line2' .. 'line9', 'fo' .. 'fx', 'line2', 'line3'); # example line

#my $ignore = shift;  # first argument is ignore.txt
#open my $fh, '<', $ignore or die $!; 
#chomp(my @ignore = <$fh>);
#close $fh;

my @result;

my %lookup = map { $_ => 0 } @ignore;
my $rx = join '|', map quotemeta, @ignore;

#while (<>) {  # This processes the remaining arguments, input.txt etc
for (@input) { # example line
    chomp;     # Required to avoid bugs due to missing newline at eof
    if (/($rx)/) {
        $lookup{$1}++;
    } else {
        push @result, $_;
    }
}

#say for @result;       # This will emulate grep
print Dumper \%lookup;  # example line
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'line6' => 1,
          'line1' => 0,
          'line5' => 1,
          'line2' => 2,
          'line9' => 1,
          'line3' => 2,
          'line8' => 1,
          'line4' => 1,
          'line7' => 1
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are both `ignore.txt` and `input.txt` sorted?

If so, you can use the [comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command!

```
$ comm -12 ignore.txt input.txt
```

How many lines are ignored?

```
$ comm -12 ignore.txt input.txt | wc -l
```

Or, if you want to do more processing, combine `comm` with `awk`.:

```
$ comm ignore.txt input.txt | awk '
    END {print "Ignored lines = " igtotal " Lines not ignored = "commtotal " Lines unique to Ignore file = " uniqtotal}
    {
       if ($0 !~ /^\t/) {uniqtotal+=1}
       if ($0 ~ /^\t[^\t]/) {commtotal+=1}
       if ($0 ~ /^\t\t/) {igtotal+=1}
    }'
```

Here I'm taking advantage with the tabs that are placed in the output by the `comm` command:
* If there are no tabs, the line is in `ignore.txt` only.
* If there is a single tab, it is in input.txt only
* If there are two tabs, the line is in both files.

By the way, not all the lines in `ignore.txt` are ignored. If the line isn't also in input.txt, the line can't really be said to be *ignored*.

### With Dennis Williamson's Suggestion

```
comm ignore.txt input.txt | awk '
   !/^\t/ {uniqtotal++}
   /^\t[^\t]/ {commtotal++}
   /^\t\t/ {igtotal++}
     END {print "Ignored lines = " igtotal " Lines not ignored = "commtotal " Lines unique to Ignore file = " uniqtotal}'
```

Comment: `var++` works, `$o` is a typo, putting `END` at the beginning irritates me (sorry), you can omit the outer set of curly braces and the `if()` statements and the `$0`: `!/^\t/ {uniqtotal++}` and `/^\t[^\t]/ {commtotal++}` work

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Thanks for spotting the typo. I cut and pasted this from my test. Sometimes, when going over the post, I _fix_ things up before I post. I sometimes accidentally delete something and retype it. Maybe that's where the `$o` came from. You're right in most of your comments. I was doing a quick test, and simply did stuff that I knew worked even if it's a bit more to type. As for the outer curly braces, I need them with my version of awk.

Comment: What version of awk? You need the outer curly braces if you use `if`, but you shouldn't need them if you use `/.../ {...}` (without the `if`, as I described in my previous comment).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Okay. I see, you still have the curly braces around the increment. Added your suggested format to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the number of ignored matches along with the matching pattern:

```
grep -of ignore.txt input.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

For example:

```
$ perl -le 'print "Coroline" . ++$s for 1 .. 21' > input.txt
$ perl -le 'print "line2\nline14"'               > ignore.txt

$ grep -of ignore.txt input.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1 line14
      3 line2
```

I.e., A line matching "line14" was ignored once. A line matching "line2" was ignored 3 times.

If you just wanted to count the total ignored lines this would work:

```
grep -cof ignore.txt input.txt
```

Update: modified the example above to use strings so that the output is a little clearer.

Comment: This counts matches of the pattern, not non-matches. You would needto subtract the resulting count per pattern from the total line count for the file to get the number of ignored lines.

Comment: @Sorpigal. Not quite. It does count the number of matches but these are the matches that would be ignored when run under `-v`. For example running the OPs `-vf` against the 25 line `file.txt` created above gives a line count of 21, i.e, 4 lines have been ignored. My one-liner above gives the breakdown of those 4 ignored lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r pattern ; do
        printf '%s:' "$pattern"
        grep -c -v "$pattern" input.txt
done < ignore.txt
```

`grep` with `-c` counts matching lines, but with `-v` added it counts non-matching lines. So, simply loop over the patterns and count once for each pattern.

Comment: One of us has this backwards. The OP asks "to know how many lines of input.txt were ignored by ignoring line1". Your code appears to count the number of lines of input.txt that aren't ignored by a pattern.

Comment: @jmcnamara: Yes, one of us has it backwards. The OP confuses matters by asking for "ignored lines" from a list of patterns called "ignore.txt" - is ignored lines those matching or NOT matching the ignore patterns? To me the wording sounds like not-matching ignore is the count he wants; I have posted a clarifying question.

Comment: See my comment on tadmc's answer. You're calling `grep` potentially _many_ times and reading the _whole_ file _each_ time.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I know this. It's not a very efficient solution. If efficiency is that important a more complicated solution is necessary, whether in perl or in shell.